# Tomcat deployment failed with Spring and CXF servlets

Tags: spring, tomcat, cxf

I am trying to run example which had Spring security included, but I removed that part from my `web.xml`. Now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- 
            <init-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>
                    WEB-INF/cxf.xml
                    WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
                </param-value></init-param>
    -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fsmsc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
            <param-value>test-profile</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fsmsc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When I deploy, I get this error:

> > **SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> >     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/TypeConverter**  at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
> >     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)   at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)  at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:962)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
> >       at
> >     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
> >       at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.TypeConverter    at
> >     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
> >       ... 32 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError means you don't have that class (org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/TypeConverter) on your classpath. That class is contained on jettison jar, which is a dependency of CXF.

To resolve your problem check if the war file or your project dependencies have jettison on it.

More: looks like jettison is declared with provided scope on cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers pom.xml. This means you have to manually add jettison dependency directly to your pom.xml. I check that with last version of CXF: 2.7.3.

Comment: Yeah, added jettison 1.3 to my POM and it worked. I was looking at cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs dependencies instead of cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers, so I didn't understand what jar has dependency on jettison.